# How can i query mongodb with key as token in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is the mongo Document.
 what code do i need to extract all data with associated token.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "59cfb47b78a26d86cc5fdd7a"
},
"event": "Coding",
"data": [
    {
        "first_name": "Chanchal",
        "last_name": "Roshan",
        "email": "chan@gmail.com",
        "phone": "75044",
        "college": "AIT",
        "members": "1",
        "amount": "25",
        "branch": "IT",
        "token": "684695669",
        "event": "Coding"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Ravi",
        "last_name": "Raj",
        "email": "i@gmail.com",
        "phone": "89746",
        "college": "AIT",
        "members": "1",
        "amount": "250",
        "branch": "IT",
        "token": "128027522",
        "event": "Coding"
    }
],
"auth_token": "z1iZ0LnDHFhs48PlYjNHyCjeh7y1"
```

}

I am new to php, sorry for such basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean given token `XXX`, find all documents where an element of the `data`array contains `token="XXX"` and return just that element of the array, not the whole array.  This should work.  Note `data.token`and the use of the `$`positional operator in the projection (arg 2):

```
db.foo.find({"data.token":"XXX"},{"data.$":1});
```